# MongoDB ODBC Connector is not able to fetch new fields/columns Into BI. currently using CData connector, it giving error

Tags: excel, mongodb, powerbi, database-connection, jdbc-odbc

Apart from MongoDB ODBC Connector I found some third party connectors

- CData: https://www.cdata.com/drivers/mongodb/odbc/
- devart: https://www.devart.com/odbc/mongodb/
- EasySoft:
  https://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-mongodb-driver/index.html
- Simba: https://www.simba.com/drivers/mongodb-odbc-jdbc/
- Dremio: https://www.dremio.com/drivers/odbc

But none of them is for free, you have to spend some money I guess.

CData MongoDB connector is giving this error. any idea how to resolve this error?

[image]

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)